# Javascript convert object with array string keys to key/name value's

Tags: javascript

I have an object with named keys like this

```
{ 
 'name[first]': 'john',
 'name[last]': 'doe'
 }
```

that I want to convert to:

```
{ 
 'name' : {
     'first' : 'john',
     'last' : 'doe'
   }
 }
```

Any idea on an elegent way to do this?

Comment: Have you found an inelegant way to do that? See [ask]. We expect people to have done a minimum of research before asking a question.

Comment: would `name` word always be static in those *string keys*?

Comment: Would your data also have `'age': 21` or `'person[address[city]]': 'Tokyo'`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `reduce()` to return obj and regular expression to split key.

```js
var obj = {
  'name[first]': 'john',
  'name[last]': 'doe'
}

var result = Object.keys(obj).reduce(function(r, e) {
  var key = e.split(/\[(.*?)\]/)
  if (!r[key[0]]) r[key[0]] = {}
  r[key[0]][key[1]] = obj[e]
  return r;
}, {})

console.log(result)
```

For nested key structure you could again use reduce but with different approach to keys but then you face problem of `deep merge` of object and for that you can use lodash.

```js
var obj = {
  'name[first[foo]]': 'john',
  'name[last]': 'doe',
  'name[last[foo[bar]]]': 'doe'
}

var result = Object.keys(obj).reduce(function(r, e) {
  var key = e.replace(/\[/g, '.').replace(/\]/g, '').split('.')
  var o = {}

  key.reduce(function(re, el, i) {
    return i != key.length - 1 ? re[el] = {} : re[el] = obj[e]
  }, o)

  r = _.merge(r, o)
  return r;
}, {})

console.log(JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.15.0/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: No response to my comment in the question, but how would you extend this if this were also possible, `'person[address[city]]': 'Tokyo'`, as well as more deeply nested structures?

Comment: @Scott Sauyet I updated my answer for nested structures.

Answer (score 1):

Using a `for..in` loop and constructing a new object:

```js
var obj = {
    'name[first]': 'john',
    'name[last]': 'doe'
};

var newObj = {}
for (var key in obj) {
    var parts = key.split(/\[|\]/);
    if(!newObj.hasOwnProperty(parts[0]))
      newObj[parts[0]] = {};
    newObj[parts[0]][parts[1]] = obj[key];
}

console.log(newObj);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```js
var obj = {
  'name[first]': 'john',
  'name[last]': 'doe'
}

var result = Object.keys(obj).reduce(function(newObj, prop) { 
  var key = prop.split(/\[|\]/)[1];  
  newObj[key] = obj[prop];
  return newObj;
}, {})
  
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution using `Object.keys`, `Array.prototytpe.reduce` and `String.prototype.match` functions:

```js
var obj = {'name[first]': 'john', 'name[last]': 'doe'};

var result = Object.keys(obj).reduce(function (o, key) {
  var parts = key.match(/^(\w+)\[(\w+)\]$/);
  if (!o[parts[1]]) {
    o[parts[1]] = {};            
  }
  o[parts[1]][parts[2]] = obj[key];
  return o;        
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var obj = {
  'name[first]': 'john',
  'name[last]': 'doe'
}
var newObj = {};
for (var property in obj) {
  if (obj.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
    var keys = property.match(/(\w+)/g);
    if (keys && keys.length == 2) {
      newObj[keys[0]] = newObj[keys[0]] || {};
      newObj[keys[0]][keys[1]] = obj[property];
    }



  }
}
console.log(newObj);
```